# Something like conditional seq_along on grouped data

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to generate 'episodes' of observations, grouping together observations where they occur `</=` 14 days apart. 
With dplyr I've managed to calculate the number of days since the last observation. However, I cannot figure out how to get a new id based on the conditional `</= 14` without a `for` loop.

Sample data:

`#obsvn is number of days since first observation in group`

```
dat <- data.frame(id = c(rep("A",5), rep("B", 2)), 
                  obsvn = c(1, 2, 29, 30, 45, 1, 15))
  id obsvn
1  A     1
2  A     2
3  A    29
4  A    30
5  A    45
6  B     1
7  B    15
```

Expected output:

```
  id obsvn ith
1  A     1    1
2  A     2    1
3  A    29    2
4  A    30    2
5  A    45    3
6  B     1    1
7  B    15    2
```

I've tried using lag to

```
dat <- dat %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(ith = 1,
         ith = ifelse(obsvn - lag(obsvn) <= 14, lag(ith), lag(ith)+1))
dat
Source: local data frame [7 x 3]
Groups: id

  id obsvn ith
1  A     1  NA
2  A     2   1
3  A    29   2
4  A    30   1
5  A    45   2
6  B     1  NA
7  B    15   1
```

Which isn't what I want. I don't understand why `ith` in row 4 is 1 rather than 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because it is returning `lag(ith)`, which is always 1 (or NA at the start).

I would do it using `diff` and `cumsum`:

```
dat %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(ith = cumsum(c(1,diff(obsvn)>=14)))
Source: local data frame [7 x 3]
Groups: id

  id obsvn ith
1  A     1   1
2  A     2   1
3  A    29   2
4  A    30   2
5  A    45   3
6  B     1   1
7  B    15   2
```

Comment: I realize this is an old post but THANK YOU - this is exactly what I needed. I don't completely understand the c(1, diff()) part though, could you elaborate a little bit? I've never seen something like this with cumsum before.

Comment: @Knachman Because `diff` returns the differences between the numbers, you always end up with a vector one shorter than the original. So you combine with with a starting number.